# Why Microsoft OneNote can show a link to the contents are copied from?

Tags: windows

When I copied some good information online and pasted them on Microsoft OneNote, it can tell that

> Pasted from [website_address]

I have done some search, but hard to find how they did this. How to add this feature to a software?

Comment: It is part of [the HTML clipboard format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa767917).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the HTML clipboard format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa767917), there is an optional `SourceURL` property in the description section of the HTML clipboard data. You can also extract it from the `BASE` element in the HTML fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the website / web-page itself has javascript code that appends that text to anything copied from it. If this is the case you will see it when pasting into even notepad.exe

The main provider of such code is tynt.com and a lot of people find it annoying.

Comment: That's interesting. I think OneNote may have something more, because it can tell every content I pasted on it where are they from.